# How do I stop Amazon Web Services from prompting for an access key?

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services

I get this window every time I start up Eclipse:

[image: Amazon Web Service]

How do I disable this window from starting up with Eclipse?

My Amazon SDK is completely up-to-date. Does anyone even have a method to stopping this?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you've got the latest versions of the plugins installed.  This bug was present in one version of the plugins, but it should be fixed in the latest versions.

Try updating from the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse update site at: http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse

If the latest plugin versions don't stop this from showing up each time you launch Eclipse, then let us know and we'll debug through it.

Comment: I have version 2.0.0.v201212211205 of AWS SDK for Java and version 1.0.0.v201202211329 of AWS Simple Workflow Tools. Both of them report being up-to-date.